# Configure azure appservice with multi-container linux apps limitations

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, containers

Based on the link below Multi-containers are currently in preview. The following App Service platform features are not supported:

Questions :

1. What does Authentication / Authorization mean here ?

---

- Authentication / Authorization
- Managed Identities
- CORS
- VNET integration is not supported for Docker Compose scenarios
- Docker Compose on Azure App Services currently has a limit of 4,000 characters at this time.

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux